# Getting a docker build ready for (Heroku) deployment?

Tags: docker

I've got a local application working using `docker-compose up`, this gets me the servers I need and they function just fine locally.

Now I've tried getting a `build.sh` started, but I can't figure out how to build a docker image using either `docker-compose` or just regular `docker-cli` with the final result of the build process. (The `/dist/` folder).

Could somebody explain to me how a regular process like this would look like, and what steps a build process would walk through in docker terms?
Would I need a seperate command to package it for deployment? Is there a separate configuration required?

Answer (score 1):

For building docker image using `docker-compose` you can add `build:` field to the service you want to build and assign to it the path of the `Dockerfile` for example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    volumes:
     - /project:/var/www/html
```

This example define a web service which:

- Uses an image that’s built from the `Dockerfile` in the current directory.
- Forwards the exposed port 80 on the container to port 8080 on the
  host machine
- Mounts the project directory on the host to `/project` inside the
  container, allowing you to modify the code without having to rebuild
  the image.

To build the image, simply issue the build command via docker-compose, as such: `docker-compose build`.

Comment: Additionally, you can specify an image name by providing the "image" key. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build